# What's wrong with my simple jquery "hello world" page?

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple jquery test page and I can't seem to get even the basics to work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type=”text/javascript”>
            $(function(){
                alert('hi');
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is a test
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, I just want an alert box to pop up when the page is ready.

There are no errors on the page but the alert box doesn't show up. This seems to be a very, very simple page to me so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Oh, whoops! I got it to work. The problem was the quotes around the second "text/javascript". They were copied and pasted and don't seem to have been copied over as regular quotes, they're some other ascii character. Simple fix... I'll try to delete this question if I can

Comment: can't seem to delete it, or answer my own question, so I posted it as a comment... Oh well

Comment: I found it too in about the same time as you, lol.. :)

Comment: @Luwe - it doesn't allow me to unless I have 100 rep. I'll just accept Shadow Wizard's instead

Comment: For the record, you couldn't delete the question because you got answers. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) as reference.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - I was ready to delete before there were any answers :)

Comment: Weird.. what message you got when trying to delete? You remember?

Comment: There's just no delete link for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of possible problems: missing `DOCTYPE` and wrong quotes around `type` attribute of the `script` tag.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                alert('hi');
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is a test
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, that's it! the doctype isn't a problem but changing the quotes did it. I realized pretty fast and tried to answer my own question, or even delete the question, but don't have enough rep :) Can't vote you up but will accept your answer

Comment: No problem, you still better have DOCTYPE if you'll check, all websites got it and it's pretty important to have for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Your Tags are worng  `<script type=”text/javascript”>` should be

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                alert('hi');
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is a test
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 <script type=”text/javascript”>
```

to

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

”  ---->>> "
```